# Javafx and Sun.glass robot causing problems IllegalStateException due to use of Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX controller which moves the mouse once in every 5 seconds. This controller also does some other work concurrently while doing this. Hence I used separate threads for each of these tasks. Below is my code:

```
Thread dynamicMouseThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isRunning = true;
        long timeout = 5000;
        int x = 5;
        Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
            x = x == 5 ? x + 5 : 5;
            robot.mouseMove(x, 5);  // This line causes the error.
        }
    }
});


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    dynamicTimerThread.setName("Dynamic Timer Thread");
    dynamicMouseThread.setName("Dynamic Mouse Thread");
    dynamicTimerThread.start();
    dynamicMouseThread.start();
}
```

This is the error I seem to be getting. Please help me out. what am I doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "Dynamic Mouse Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = Dynamic Mouse Thread
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:427)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:52)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinRobot.<init>(WinRobot.java:33)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.createRobot(WinApplication.java:205)
at main.SubDocumentController$1.run(SubDocumentController.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is slightly misleading, it should really be referring to the [*JavaFX Application Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm#A1107438), which is where all access to JavaFX objects must happen.

In JavaFX you shouldn't be creating threads like this. There are concurrency classes for this in the `javafx.concurrent` package, such as [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [`Worker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) which essentially wrap a `Runnable` for you. Use [`Platform#runLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to execute these in the right context.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
        // ...
        robot.mouseMove(x, 5);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did try using Platform.runLater but it resulted in the same exception. Also, when I used the Task as a wrapper, I had no exception but the mouse wouldn't move which was pretty strange cos I knew some exception occurred.

Comment: Odd. The error you're getting should be fixed with `runLater`. A quick search found [this blog post](http://ustesis.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/headless-ui-testing-with-testfx-and-javafx-8/) which also uses exactly the same mechanism I suggested, for the Glass robot...

Comment: Actually my Task implementation was slightly faulty. However, your comment helped me re-evaluate that. It works now. Thanks.